# Google Ads API. Hot to retrieve detailed information for customers ads accounts

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Currently we are moving from `google-ads-node` package to `google-ads-api`.

The **main problem** that we can not retrieve detailed information about customers ads account.

The method `Client.listAccessibleCustomers` work just fine but it retrieve only following data

```
[ `customers/${customerID}`, `customers/${customerID}`, ... ]
```

**But we need all the data from the customer ads account**

There is a file in package [ServiceFactory](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Opteo/google-ads-api/f2ed2721c635929fa0848f2f174d42b5bc60067f/src/protos/autogen/serviceFactory.ts) which `extends` each exported `class` (place in a raw mode because it's huge)

There is a getter `public get customers` which retrieve some methods to get them, but there is also **warning** that you shouldn't use it in production, so how I should retrieve this info?

Even if I try to use it I've get the following error

```
    {
       "errors": [
           {
             "error_code": {
               "authorization_error": 24
             },
             "message": "The customer can't be used because it isn't enabled."
         }
       ]
    }
```

On `google-ads-node` there aren't any errors and we get the result, but they advice to move to `google-ads-api`

Answer (score 0):

You should build a query

```
const customer = new Customer(clientOptions,customerOptions)

let data = await customer.query('SELECT customer_client.descriptive_name, customer_client.id FROM customer_client')
```

And so on...